# How to start working with Xcode

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I am developing an iPhone Native App. So can any tell me how to start working with Xcode? I have created Hello world program. My requirement is "I am having 2 drop down list and a button, where both the drop down list are fetching data from DB." I tried searching for drop down list in Interface Builder but unable to find it. Can anyone guide me how can I proceed for this?

Thanks in advance.

-Ankit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "drop down list" with the default interface elements in iOS. You'll either want to use a `UIPickerView` or a `UITableView`, depending on your application.

The easiest way to get started with `UITableView` is to use Xcode to create a new Navigation-Based app with Core Data for storage. This will setup most of the basic stuff for you and you can either tweak it to suit your needs or you can just see how the interface and data elements interact with each other.